# Swift - Tableview won't reload correctly after loading for the second time

Tags: arrays, json, swift, uitableview, sorting

I am a little confused about how my Tableview is reacting. My problem is that the Tableview shows the other order than Dictionary than when I print the Dictionary. When I print the Dictionary everything seems to be fine, but when I look at my phone the tableview is showing the cell at a random order again.

First I fetch the JSON.

```
    var Aanbiedingen_bieren = [Aanbiedingen_bier]()
    var Aanbiedingen_bieren_Filter = [Aanbiedingen_bier]()
```

Fetch data.

```
func fetchData() {
    Aanbiedingen_bieren_Filter.removeAll()
    Aanbiedingen_bieren.removeAll()
    let url_Aanbiedingen_bier = URL(string: "\(Firebase_url)")
    let downloadURL = url_Aanbiedingen_bier
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: downloadURL!) { data, urlResponse, error in
        let data = data
        print("downloaded")
        do
        {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let downloadedBiers = try decoder.decode(SheetJS.self, from: data!)
            self.Aanbiedingen_bieren = downloadedBiers.SheetJS

            for jsonData in self.Aanbiedingen_bieren {
                let Soort = jsonData.Title
                if self.Soort_Bier == "Alles" {
                    self.Aanbiedingen_bieren_Filter.append(jsonData)
                }else{
                    if self.Soort_Bier == "Krat" {
                        if Soort.contains(word: "Krat") {
                            self.Aanbiedingen_bieren_Filter.append(jsonData)
                        }
                    }
                    if self.Soort_Bier == "Fles" {
                        if Soort.contains(word: "Fles") {
                            self.Aanbiedingen_bieren_Filter.append(jsonData)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            self.Aanbiedingen_bieren_Filter = self.Aanbiedingen_bieren_Filter.sorted(by: {$0.Voor_prijs.compare($1.Voor_prijs, options: .numeric) == .orderedAscending})
            print(self.Aanbiedingen_bieren_Filter)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

The first time that the code runs the `Soort_Bier = "Alles"`. After a button tap the `Soort_Bier` will change in `Soort_bier = "Krat"`. After the data was loaded for a second time I first wanted to filter the data. I have this done by implementing an if statement that checks if the Title of the JSON has a specific word in the String and if so append it to an other array. After that, I wanted to sort the price. When the sorting is finished I wanted to print the Dictionary to see if the sorting is correct. This still seems to be the case. Then I want to reload the tableView so all of the cells will show and here is something wrong. When I want to load the dictionary for the second time, it doesn't seem to reload the tableView correctly.

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return Aanbiedingen_bieren_Filter.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Aanbiedingen_bieren_Cell", for: indexPath) as! Aanbiedingen_bieren_Cell

        let Aanbiedingen_bier = self.Aanbiedingen_bieren_Filter[indexPath.row]
        cell.Aanbiedingen_bier = Aanbiedingen_bier

        return cell
    }
```

Struct:

```
struct SheetJS: Codable {
    var SheetJS: [Aanbiedingen_bier]

    init(SheetJS: [Aanbiedingen_bier]) {
        self.SheetJS = SheetJS
    }
}

struct Aanbiedingen_bier: Codable {
    let Logo_Image: String
    let Van_prijs: String
    let Voor_prijs: String
    let Beschrijving: String
    let Item_Image: String
    let Title: String
    let Bestel_Online_link: String
    let Footer_item: String
    let Item_1: String
    let Item_2: String

    init(Logo_Image: String, Item_Image: String, Van_prijs: String, Voor_prijs: String, Beschrijving: String, Title: String, Item_1: String, Item_2: String, Bestel_Online_link: String, Footer_item: String) {
        self.Logo_Image = Logo_Image
        self.Title = Title
        self.Item_Image = Item_Image
        self.Beschrijving = Beschrijving
        self.Van_prijs = Van_prijs
        self.Voor_prijs = Voor_prijs
        self.Item_1 = Item_1
        self.Item_2 = Item_2
        self.Bestel_Online_link = Bestel_Online_link
        self.Footer_item = Footer_item

    }
}
```

JSON:

```
{
  "SheetJS": [
    {
      "Logo_Image": "https://www.biernet.nl/images/winkel/17335-agrimarkt.gif",
      "Van_prijs": "€16,99",
      "Voor_prijs": "€10,49",
      "Beschrijving": "Krat 24x0,30",
      "Item_Image": "https://www.biernet.nl/images/soort/23026-grolsch%20krat%20normale%20flesjes%2030%20cl.png",
      "Title": "Grolsch Premium Pilsener",
      "Bestel_Online_link": "",
      "Footer_item": "t/m zaterdag 3 augustus",
      "Item_1": "€6,50 korting (38%)",
      "Item_2": "€1,46 per liter"
    },//Some more data
  ]
}
```

Only price printed of dictionary:

```
€5,39
€5,94
€6,39
€6,39
€7,64
€16,19
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCytv.jpg)

Please let me know if you want more information or code.

Comment: What do you mean by reloading "correctly"? You are clearing the data and reloading again...

Comment: When I `print(self.Aanbiedingen_bieren_Filter)`, it will show correctly (price low to high), but the tableView will show an other order (See picture). That why I think that it is not loading correctly, or it must be something else that I am not aware of.

Comment: Right, but where are you calling this reloading of the data? The second time...

Comment: @Dani010- Please perform whole code of do block in the main thread. instead of only reloading table data

Comment: @SalvadorMolina The first time I will call the function named: `fetchData()`. When you press a button the `Soort_Bier` will change in `Soort_Bier = "Prijs"` and after that the function named: `fetchData()` will be called for the second time.

Comment: @DevendraAgnihotri Doesn't seem to do the trick. It's still not showing up correctly for the second time. The strange ting is, that if I run the code for the first time with `Soort_Bier = "Prijs"` everything seems to be just fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's because items in Dictionary ordered randomly.

If you want to order it, you should use 'Set' another ordered collection type.

Or see the Apple Document below

> Apple Docs : The order of key-value pairs in a dictionary is stable between mutations but is otherwise unpredictable. If you need an ordered collection of key-value pairs and don’t need the fast key lookup that Dictionary provides, see the KeyValuePairs type for an alternative.

Comment: Hi, I am still trying to get it working. I can't seem to get my code working with 'Set'. Can please give me more explanation how to get this working?

Comment: Hmm...I look your code again, and it's not dictionary type. So I think reloading tableview is not working correctly.. Have you print Aanbiedingen_bieren_Filter inside the tableView cellForRowAt method?

Answer (score 0):

I think you haven't been using wrongly data collection. You should use array to order. Because A dictionary stores associations between keys of the same type and values of the same type in a collection with no defined ordering. Unlike array, a dictionary do not have a specified order.

Click [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html)! to read about data collection in swift

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reaction. It seems that the url is not working. Can you please update the url?

Comment: Thank you. I have a question. You say I need to use an array if I want to have a specific order in my tableView. But how can I set the JSON data as best to an array?